# Bootstrap 4 border utilities

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I feel like this should be obvious to find but I have not come up with anything. Bootstrap 4 has utility class for adding and removing a border, but is there support for defining the border width or style like solid or dashed?

```
<span class="border"></span>
<span class="border-top"></span>
<span class="border-right"></span>
<span class="border-bottom"></span>
<span class="border-left"></span>
```

There are some classes that changes the margins and padding such as `mr-3` and `pt-2`.

Maybe I just need to define them myself?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No, there are no classes in Bootstrap 4 for border width or style.

You can simply add something like:

```
.border-3 {
    border-width:3px !important;
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/ktnEeWExvh

NOTE: `!important` is needed in this case because Bootstrap also uses !important in many of the [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) like `border-*`.

Answer (score 8):

Suggests to add a bootstrap extension.

```
/* _border-width-customs.scss */
$border-width-custom-1: 1px !default;
$border-width-custom-2: 2px !default;
$border-width-custom-3: 3px !default;
$border-width-custom-4: 4px !default;
$border-width-custom-5: 5px !default;
$border-width-custom-6: 6px !default;
$border-width-custom-7: 7px !default;
$border-width-custom-8: 8px !default;

$border-width-customs: ("1": $border-width-custom-1, "2": $border-width-custom-2, "3": $border-width-custom-3, "4": $border-width-custom-4, "5": $border-width-custom-5, "6": $border-width-custom-6, "7": $border-width-custom-7, "8": $border-width-custom-8);

@each $name, $size in $border-width-customs {
    @each $var in '', 'top-', 'right-', 'bottom-', 'left-' {
        .border-#{$var}#{$name} { border-#{$var}width: $size !important; border-#{$var}style: solid; border-#{$var}color: $border-color;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer deserving a little more context and explanation.
For the ones wondering: this SCSS snippet creates a bunch of classes useful to assign a different size to every single border of an element. You can have i.e.: `border-left-6 border-bottom-1` classes set to an element, resulting in a thick left border and an extremely thin bottom border.

Comment: I had to log in just to +1 this. Great solution :D

Answer (score 5):

In bootstrap 4 for borders you can use only :

- Borders - add remove borders
- Border color
- Border Radius
- Float
- Responsive Floats
- Center Align
- Width
- Height
- Spacing

You can create your own classes, something like :

```css
.border-dotted{
 border-style: dotted;
}
.border-10{
border-style:solid;
 border-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="border-dotted">Hi</h1>
<h1 class="border-10">Hi!</h1>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, even if I set the property to !important. Bootstrap overrides it

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Bootstrap's Border Documentation.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/)

There are basic styling classes set up (similar to the btn-default, btn-warning) sets and border radius. But any other styling would need to be done yourself.

The reason for this would be that there is either not enough demand for Bootstrap to add this natively into their framework, there are too many options to efficiently define, or how simple it is to write them in your own classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have bootstrap npm library and if you look at _variable.scss you will find
**$border-width:                1px !default;**

You can override it by creating a new scss file where you can import bootstrap modules.

```
$myborder-width : 3px;

$border-width:$myborder-width;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";(you can include only the required modules here)
```

you can convert this main.scss file to css and use this css instead of bootstrap.css in your html.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap V5 you can do this

```
$utilities: (
  "border-width": (
    property: border-width,
    class: border,
    values: (
      1: 1px,
      2: 2px,
      3: 3px,
      4: 4px,
      5: 5px,
    )
  )
)
```