# Customizing Bootstrap SCSS

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I have just started to set an ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC application. 
Bootstrap 4 comes with it and it also has a site.css.

One of the bootstrap classes overridden is the border and i change it to the below

```
.border-top {
  border-top: 20px dashed yellow;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 20px dotted red;
}
```

In the layout the order is

But why are the styles that i put in for border top and border-bottom do not reflect?

I took a very basic example of customizing bootstrap's default style for border and this is directly from asp.net core mvc default project.

This is just invalidating my understanding of how to customize bootstrap styles

Could someone help me with this.

[browserinspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi1B3.png)

Comment: As you can see, the Bootstrap util classes like borders use `!important` .. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506610/bootstrap-4-border-utilities/48506639#48506639

Comment: So it comes down to certain things with border that cannot be over-ridden and bootstrap has always the final say. The only option would be create a custom border class with a name and style the way we want. Is this like documented somewhere in bootstrap where certain things cannot be overridden? I literally spent 2 hours trying to make it work. Thanks for your help